# Procedure to Insert into table and its columns by given parameters?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, blob

i`ll start this with some code...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOAD_IMAGE_INTO_TABLE (
    imgDir varchar2 
    , imgName varchar2
    , destTable varchar2
    , destIndex varchar2
    , destBlob varchar2)
 AS 
        fHnd            bfile;  
        b               blob;  
        srcOffset       integer := 1;  
        dstOffset       integer := 1;  
BEGIN
  dbms_lob.CreateTemporary( b, true );  
  fHnd := BFilename( imgDir, imgName );  
  dbms_lob.FileOpen( fHnd, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY );  
  dbms_lob.LoadFromFile( b, fHnd, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, dstOffset, srcOffset ); 
  --insert into (Select * From user_tables Where table_name = destTable) values(imgName,b);
  --insert into destTable (destIndex, destBlob) values( imgName, b );  
  commit;  
  dbms_lob.FileClose( fHnd );  
END LOAD_IMAGE_INTO_TABLE;
```

As you might see, I am trying to create a procedure which puts an image into a table. Target table name  and column names (for imgname and blobfile) will be given as parameters.

Both ways I tried didn't work. (see --insert(...) in code)

Maybe you have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't pass table names as arguments in dml clause. Check out  ```EXECUTE IMMEDIATE``` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Do you really have so many tables for storing images that you need to parameterise the table name and column name?

Comment: @KoenLostrie ok thanks, gonna try that

Comment: @APC actually not, but i thought its better than havin multiple Procedures doin the same thing.

Comment: Inserting into different tables is not *"havin multiple Procedures doin the same thing"*. It's having multiple procedures doing **similar things**. One option to reduce repetition would be to have a package. Write a standard procedure to load the file into a PL/SQL variable, then write procedures for loading named tables which call that procedure. Using dynamic SQL is an alternate solution. Generally speaking I dislike using dynamic SQL for application code: it's potentially risky, it's harder to debug and of course impact analysis becomes harder.